# Difficulty Tracking Form Submissions with GTM on WordPress + Elementor Pro

Tags: wordpress, google-tag-manager, elementor

I'm seeking assistance with tracking form submissions on my WordPress site [www.supertilt.fr](http://www.supertilt.fr), specifically with Elementor Pro.

**Technical Context:
**
I have two distinct forms on the site: one for "Contact" and another for "Quote requests."
The forms do not have unique IDs and are embedded using Elementor Pro.
I've previously used the click text "send" for the quote form and "I contact supertilt" for the contact form as distinguishing elements.
The successful submission of these forms doesn't redirect to a thank-you page but instead displays an on-page message: "Your message has been sent."

**Problem:**

My tracking tags in GTM are firing even when the form is not successfully submitted. So the results are skewed, and the tracking doesn't reflect actual successful submissions.

**Solutions Attempted:
**
Using h2 Text as a Marker: Since the forms had different h2 texts above them ("Contact us" and "Request a quote"), I tried using these to distinguish between the forms. However, other h2 elements on the page interfered with this method.
Click Text Method: Using GTM, I set up tags based on the "click text" of the form submission buttons. The issue is that the tags get triggered even when the buttons are not clicked.
Page URL Differentiation: Tried differentiating forms based on the page URL. The GTM preview shows the correct values for "click classes" and "Page URL", but the tag still doesn't fire on form submission.

Checking for formSubmit Event: When checking the GTM preview, there doesn't seem to be any "formSubmit" event triggering upon the form submission, indicating that GTM may not be detecting the form submission event at all.

Given the above, I am at an impasse. Is anyone familiar with these challenges or have suggestions on how to properly track form submissions in such a context? Any insights or experiences shared would be immensely appreciated.

Thank you for your time and assistance!